# fill in hole following curve

Tags: modifiers, objects, bezier-curves, 3d-printing

I have made a panel for my car dash to 3d print. The problem is at some point I cut out a large hole with a boolean operation so I could test the part easier and save time and plastic.

The file is located at

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/189370/problem.blend

and the image is

[image]

Is there any way to fill this hole keep the front contour of the part ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got what you ask, in this particular case should be easy:

After activating vertex snapping, select the side profile (which still has the right vertical curvature), and extrude that vertex edge snapping to horizontal edge (which still has horizontal curvature), and in the end you'll cover the entire missing panel.

Like this:

[image]

[image]

If you still have original shapes, though, you could also use booleans twice: the first as you did, as "difference", to cut the hole, and another one as "intersect", to get the cut panel as indipendent shape.

**edit:**

Since you like learning new tricks, I'll add another one here below, although I couldn't use it in your specific case, probably due to the specific topology you had in that file.

Here's the trick: if you have a "missing" surface, similar to what you had:

[image]

you can sometimes "reconstruct" it using the "grid fill" tool, like this:

[image]

which is way more elegant than manually reconstruct it... good to know, I think.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to learn a new trick. I tried the second method first before I saw your answer. It did work but I had all manor of non manifold problems.
Your first method was quite clean and will help me in other situations. Thanks

Comment: Good! I just added another (somewhat more cool) way to solve this problem, above, it doesn't matter if I couldn't apply it to your file...