# Filling Hole in scanned ct - object

Tags: 3d-printing

So my problem is that I have an scanned object (CT scan) and there are some "errors". One of them is that there are holes in the object, which I don't want.

[image: Hole]
[image: Hole]

[image]

My first solution was just to put an object in it and modify it to match it. I want to ask you, whether there is a better methode to fill that hole? Any hints or ideas would be helpful.

I tried:
a) Delete Faces, Select edges and (f). Works
b) Add an object and some boolean operation. Works <- favorite till now

Comment: blender "objects" imho can't have "holes", their mesh can have holes. so maybe your phisical object has holes, and thus after scanning your 3d object has a mesh which has holes....? if so, you need to reconstruct part of the mesh to fill the holes. Here the existing topology is complex... I would try to "boolean intersect" with a "patching" object, surrounding your hole. Then apply and adjust the new "intersect" patch generated...

Comment: I think your understanding on what a mesh and an object in blender is, is a bit wrong. There is a hole in your mesh. But not in your object. If you add a cube in Blender, you create an object with the cube-mesh in it. To your problem: Why don't you just select the edges around the hole and fill them (f) ?

Comment: Sry, english is not my native language. I looking for that problem on google and all I found was "hole in mesh", and I don't know how to describe it correctly. @m.ardito it is a ct scan so it's not clean

Comment: @reaper I tried to, but you need to much time to select all edges and it's not very clean.

Comment: @kami1991 if you wish a solution perfectly fit to your complex mesh, the best would be to upload on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ at least an example of one of your "holes" (then edit the question and add the provided link).

Comment: @m.ardito Done.

Comment: as reaper said, one way could be using fill, but you could also try grid fill as in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71349/fill-in-hole-following-curve. As I said also booleans could help you but some refinement is always needed. No automatic clean reconstruction, imho is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying with your file, I would do like this:

In edit mode, delete all vertices that shouldn't be there. This depends on how the original model was: if holes are scanning errors, some geometry is missing, because of the hole obviously, but the reconstruction also created some non-existing surface geometry to create that wrong hole.

After doing that, your mesh will be non manifold, but you should have - on each side of the whole - a "ring" of vertices that should be quite easy for you to fill with tools like [**Grid Fill**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html?highlight=grid%20fill#grid-fill), hopefully (I tried with one of your holes, I'll add images below to document.

This is the most "clean" method imho, and quite easy to do, but manually not automatic. And to reconstruct the missing geometry (eg with grid fill) you'll have to try to stick to your original object surface, visually from a reference... (or doing another scan of that area, perhaps?)

This is the hole I'm going to reconstruct:

[image]

In edit mode, I'm going to remove this geometry which should be wrong (not sure, it depends on the original object...)

[image]

[image]

[image]

after removing those vertices, you have *two* holes, now, one on each side!

so now you can select a ring on the first side, and try using "grid fill"

[image]

the "grid fill" default settings could be not optimal

[image]

but you can tweak them in the side panel until you reach a decent result

[image]

now you switch to the "other side" hole left before (from there we still see the last geometry created on the previous side by "grid fill", selected...)

[image]

now do the same, select a vertices ring and grid fill it

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, finally, the hole is now gone and you have this (on each side):

[image]

[image]

You can still tweak vertices and faces until satisfied. Then, move to another hole... :)

Hth

Comment: A very important thing to note when using Grid Fill is that the loop ring has to be an **even number of vertices**, the tool will fail otherwise and you'll get a "select two edge loops" error.