# Subdividing arbitrary face into smaller faces

Tags: modeling, faces, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to split an arbitrary face into smaller faces hopefully making some kind of grid. What I mean by arbitrary face is a face constricted by an random number of edges. Say, for example a circle with 32 vertices. By selecting the face (in edit mode) and pressing <kbd>W</kbd>> *Subdivide* I only manage to split the edges of the face into more edges, not the face itself. 
For my purpose it doesn't matter what shapes the original face is split into, as long as its some kind og grid.

Comment: Face with more than 4 vertices won't be subdivided in smaller faces because it's an Ngon, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57534/cant-subdivide-face

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Grid Fill** to fill faceless circle.

Select all vertices, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> > **Grid Fill**, adjust **Offset** as you want, also you can check **Span** value.

> **Note:** This will only work with even number of vertices.

[image: steps]

Comment: but note, that may need an even number of vertices

Comment: @m.ardito good to point this out, I'll add this to my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: of course, every answer enhancement is good. I learnt this too from others too (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84495/filling-hole-in-scanned-ct-object/84502#84502)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a solution which can work with a odd number of vertices :

- Enter in edit mode (with TAB)
- Select the face you want to subdivide
- Press **I** (inset) and validate immediately with **ENTER**
- Press **S** (scale), enter **0** (zero) and validate with **ENTER** : you should see radius from the center of the face.
- Move the mouse cursor on a radius and press **CTRL+R**
- Turn the mouse wheel, to select the number of rings you want to create
- Validate by pressing **ENTER** two times
- Select all vertices (by pressing **A** two times)
- Press **CTRL+V** to display the *Vertice* menu
- Click on the *remove double* option.