# Fill hole with spherical cap

Tags: mesh

I had some artifacts at the pole of a sphere, which are the result of a Displace modifier with a slightly messy UV map:

[image: artifacts]

To get rid of them, I <kbd>Alt</kbd>-selected a loop around them and did *Select > Select Loop Inner-Region*:

[image: seelction]

When I now hit <kbd>Del</kbd> and choose "Dissolve Vertices", I get a single flat face:

[image: flat face]

Is there a way to instead fill the hole with something like the cap of a UV sphere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill cylinder cap with quads](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/fill-cylinder-cap-with-quads)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The cylinder in that question already has (almost) what I want and they ask how to change it into quads. If at all it's a duplicate of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71349/fill-in-hole-following-curve) but *Grid fill* does not work for sphere caps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fill a cylinder cap?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44438/how-can-i-fill-a-cylinder-cap)

Comment: Actually, this is kind of a duplicate of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44438/how-can-i-fill-a-cylinder-cap), except that I not only need the fan, but also regular loops around the (poked) center.

Answer (score 1):

Any other way will leave a flat face. The way I do it is to create the exact size UV sphere with the same amount of segments, delete the unnecessary faces, and then manually connect the vertices to the cap of the new UV Sphere.

But I'm guessing since you have so many segments that would take forever. So another more inaccurate way- since it's a sphere is...
Extrude the opening's edge 2 or 3 times. Then merge the smallest loop into a single vertice.
From there you can adjust the height of the new vertice loops until the smooth operator or subsurface takes effect visually.